# Docker container builds fine on all but one system

Tags: php, apache, docker

I have a Dockerfile and compose a script that creates 2 containers one for web (apache) and the other for (SQL), they build and run perfectly fine on a Windows 7, Linux Mint 18.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.

However, when I go to build/deploy on an AWS EC2 server, everything works great with the exception of PHP code showing as plain text.

I have browsed around and seen other articles following the example of making changes to MPM modules such as `a2enmod mpm_event` and `a2dismod mpm_prefork`. Apache on the EC2 setup appears to have all the required modules for PHP and handlers to process the `.php` extension.

At this point, I am scratching my head trying to understand why the docker web container builds differently on the EC2 server.

Comment: can you show Dockerfile, it sounds like phps not getting installed, you would see this from logs.

Comment: `FROM php:7.0-apache
#Install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y nano
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2dismod mpm_prefork
RUN a2enmod mpm_event
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN service apache2 restart
Install Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=. --filename=composer
RUN mv composer /usr/local/bin/
COPY index.php /var/www/html/
COPY api /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 443`

Comment: The above works on other systems, except AWS EC2, PHP runs perfectly fine, and the php source code does not show.